# Spring mvc Setting dropdown selected value to a session variable and use it in dao layers

Tags: spring-mvc

I am new to springmvc and trying to devlop aa application using spring mvc.I have a dropdown list of batches.like batch1,batch2,batch3 etc...Whenevr a batch is selected i have to assign that value to a variable like session variables and use across all controllers and dao's.I will pass that value to the dao layer queries.eg select * from candidate where batch_no='batch1' to fetch values.I want this value to be used acrooss all other tables related dao's also.eg i have candidate,newbatch,test1 tables.Can anyone give me some ideas  how to achieve this.Thanks in advance.